# Add a header when sending a message with php-enqueue and RabbitMQ

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, php-enqueue

I am trying to send a header using php-enqueue bundle
I'm trying this:

```
public function __construct(
    ProducerInterface    $producer
)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->producer = $producer;
}

//... Inside function...
$m = new Message(
   'message to send',
    [],
    [
       'm' => 1
    ]
);

$this->producer->sendCommand('newMessageFromApi', $m);
```

But the header does not reach the consumer.
These are the only headers that arrive.

```
[
      "content_type" => "text/plain",
      "delivery_mode" => 2,
      "message_id" => "38f96af0-64de-4a31-9315-6b51dd5f8baf",
      "timestamp" => 1652027271
]
```

Comment: See "You can choose how to send messages either using a transport directly or with the client" https://php-enqueue.github.io/bundle/message_producer/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$m = new Message('message to send',['m' => 1]);
```